# Confusion regarding PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: html, web-applications, cordova

I have a webapp developed (game), based on HTML5 + CreateJS, but since Android lacks of standards, I've run into unsolvable issues for my webapp. That's why im recurring to PhoneGap.

Yet my confusion lies in the fact that I need to make this game into a phonegap app that runs on Android/iOS, using for each platform native specific stuff.

So, should I build 2 apps (one for each platform), all over again, or use the one I have and try to deploy it into different devices using phonegap?

The truth is I don't know how to approach this problem... can anyone help?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use Cordova (PhoneGap) to create a cross platform mobile app. Basically, Cordova (PhoneGap is Adobe's version of Cordova) is an open source project that provides JavaScript API's for accessing native device functionality (like the Accelerometer or Camera.)  Cordova also lets you package your app in the native application shell, so you put your app on the app store. Please see my other answer here about Cordova and hybrid apps: [Beginning with Apache Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147671/beginning-with-apache-cordova/16151042#16151042)

If the game runs completely in HTML5, I think it would be easiest to just use that one codebase and integrate it with Cordova and then deploy to the various platforms - why rewrite the app twice if you don't need to?

However, if you are using native device functionality, you may need to develop your own Cordova/Phonegap plugins for use. This way, you can call regular Android/iOS code (Java or Objective-C code) that you write from your web app code with JavaScript. This might be more work, especially if you have never written in these languages.

Personally, since you already have a working HTML5 app, I'd just try to get it working with Cordova and see how it performs. If you really need some native specific stuff, then I'd try creating that "stuff" as a plugin. Rebuilding the app twice, once for Android and once for iOS seems like a pretty big waste of time to me.

Comment: phonegap is not adobe's version of cordova. phonegap existed before adobe got involved with phonegap ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's pretty much the same idea I have, yet I don´t know how to technically approach it.
BTW web games suck in mobiles :P

Comment: @Xander Yes, true, "Phonegap" was the name of the project when it was just starting and owned by Nitobe. Then when Adobe bought them, Adobe donated the source to Apache and the project was named "Cordova" or "Apache Cordova". PhoneGap then shifted to become the Adobe branded release of Cordova. Adobe adds extra stuff to Cordova (mostly now just PhoneGapBuild and the blog posts.) The distinction is important and we should talk about "Cordova" unless it is a specific PhoenGap issue. See Brian's blog post for more info: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

Comment: @FeleMed, if you are having issues starting, try the Getting Started docs at: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/  Keep in mind that 3.0 is very new and had some big changes so the docs might be a bit out of date. What I would do is start by building the test suite, (git clone and run this: https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/blob/master/createmobilespec.sh) then replace the /www/ folder with your web app and see if it works; tweak from there. Check out some of the Getting Started guides, and feel free to post in the #cordova or #phonegap IRC channels for immediate help.

Comment: @MBillau On a side question, do yuo know how to build Cordova apps without the build.phonegap.com website, building them locally?

Comment: @FeleMed You need to download the specific SDK's for each platform that you want, and then follow the various guides on the Cordova website. If it is Cordova 3.0, you can use the new command line tools to set up the app, add the plugins that you need, and then even generate the app. Or once you run the bin\create command, you can drop that into an IDE like Eclipse (new Android Project as From Existing Source Code) and then Run as Android App. For iOS it's pretty much the same process except that you need a Mac and need xCode. The guides should help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is either yes or no.

1. Yes if you want to use some specific feature of the native code. For instance, iOS's default objects is beautiful itself, you can easily drag and drop it to build your application. However, it takes lots of time to rebuild for another platform. Specially, if you intend to create app/game for multiple platforms, it would be a nightmare.
2. HTML5 is much faster for you to approach several platforms. However, you can't get the best result on all platforms and all devices. I mean, it is really difficult to bring the max performance of the app on all devices. For this solution, I suggest HTML5 with some libraries such as LimeJS, Crafty, Impact, etc. or some tools such as Construct 2, etc. I used to use HTML5 with all those libraries but found out that Construct 2 is much better.
3. Instead of using phonegap, I recommend cocoonjs. Specially if your targets are iOS and Android platforms.

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, even the simplest game such as bubble buster would be difficult to make cross platform with different version of android webview and you need cross platform?  I would suggest looking into something like Unity3D.

Comment: Actually it's a requirement for the game to be web based, so plugins like unity are out of our scope of reach.
Also remember you made a comment, not an answer :P